# What method should I use instead of a deprecated 'resumeAnimation(forKey:)'?

Tags: swift, scenekit

When I'm using SceneKit's `resumeAnimation(forKey:)` instance method

```
model.resumeAnimation(forKey: "run")
```

Xcode 11.7 prints the following message:

```
//
//    'resumeAnimation(forKey:)' was deprecated in macOS 10.13: 
//     Use -[SCNAnimationPlayer setPaused:] instead.
//
```

**Question**:

How to use `[SCNAnimationPlayer setPaused:]` instead of `resumeAnimation(forKey:)`?

(Available replacement has no argument with name `key`)

Comment: What’s the hard part?

Comment: The hard part is – there's no `[SCNAnimationPlayer setPaused:]` method in Swift, because it's Objective-C.

Comment: This. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnanimationplayer/2866058-paused

Comment: Thanks, I've seen it. But what's about a key? It's simple Bool. How to launch animation based on key?

Comment: _What_ about a key? Just set the property to pause or resume animation.

Comment: resumeAnimation(forKey: "run")

Comment: But if I have 10 animations with 10 different keys? How to resume a needed one?

Comment: Well now we are on to a whole new question. Maybe that is what you should have asked?

Comment: I asked about deprecated method containing a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve an `SCNAnimationPlayer` using [`animationPlayer(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnanimatable/2866026-animationplayer) and then set its `paused` property to `true`.